# Unable to load System.Windows.Controls Assembly in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I have been trying to load an assembly in powershell using command as follows:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Controls")
```

It's not working.

[image]

Comment: what error are you getting?

Also why not just use [System.Windows.Controls]?

Comment: No error, but it's not loading as other assembly are working/loading fine.

Comment: it is not returning true as other assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wells its already loaded.

Try running this.

```
$ExportedTypes = [appdomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | select ExportedTypes
Foreach($ExportedType in $ExportedTypes){
    $ExportedType.ExportedTypes | ?{$_.FullName -like "system.windows.controls*"} | select FullName, Module
}
```

If you get any results it is already loaded.

The Assembly you are loading is actually part of PresentationFramework.dll

Comment: i tried, i am not getting any result for system.windows.controls. but as you said it's a part of PresentationFramework.dll. can i load this assembly and access controls from system.windows.controls?